# Switched to a new Macbook and now edits I make in LaTeX do not show up in the PDF

Tags: pdf, compiling, texmaker

Super noob here. Apologies in advance.

I have a resume in LaTeX that a friend built for me a while back and I have been successfully modifying it since. I have very minimal LaTeX knowledge. I use Texmaker, have the newest version. I have made no recent changes to anything. Running the same code on overleaf works just fine.

My issue is that when I run quickbuild (using LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX as required) and look at the PDF, whatever changes I have made (no matter how big) do not show up in the PDF. When I delete the PDF and run quickbuild, I get a 'File not found' error.

I have a hunch that this is related to me having purchased a new computer. I switched from a 2015 Macbook to a 2020 Macbook Pro and I don't think I've use LaTeX since.

Is there any obvious likely issue here? Any help would be appreciated. Apologies in advance if I've left something important out.

Comment: I suppose the first question is have you installed tex? (texmaker is just the editor to write the source files not the actual tex system)

Comment: Yes, the tex files were migrated as well when I switched computers.

Comment: what does "migrated" mean here (it's probably simpler to re-install mactex). If you open a terminal and type `pdflatex small2e` does it run latex and make `small2e.pdf` ?

Comment: "pdflatex command not found". I suppose that could be a problem. And by "migrated" I mean I did a full backup of the old one and put it on the new one via time machine

Comment: yes but (I would guess) that only restores the files you probably still need to set up your Path to find them (but I'm not a mac user so don't trust my advice)

Comment: Did you do a full Migration from the old system to the new one? If not you may need to install a TeX Distribution. To find out what does `which pdflatex` return when run in Terminal? If you need a TeX Distribution I would suggest installing MacTeX which you can get from <https://www.tug.org/mactex/>.

Answer (score 0):

The best option IMHO  to reinstall TeX from http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html. This is my opinion from OPS chat with  @David Carlisle above.